# Do double quotes, dots and commas modify the forget weights in LSTM if retained?

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to implement custom NER with LSTM. In the pre processing steps is it required to remove the punctuation marks like double quotes, dots and commas? Do they add any significance if retained? Since each document is a collection of sentences.

Comment: Commas can save lives: Let's eat, grandpa VS. Let's eat grandpa.

Comment: Yes, they can make a difference, and also how you tokenize your sentences, e.g.:
Let's, eat , grandpa vs Let's eat, grandpa; i.e. make sure the comma is not attached to the token.

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation can carry a lot of information about where the entities start and end. For instance, it is very unlikely that an entity name would contain a single double quote, start with a comma, etc. These are all information that the RNN get grasp very quickly and help the model performance.

However, be careful, you tokenize your input text properly. If you only split the text at spaces, all punctuation remains attached to the words and it would very likely lead to unnecessary out-of-vocabulary tokens. By removing punctuation, you avoid this problem but lose important information. In Python, you can e.g., use [spacy](https://spacy.io/) or [sacremoses](https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses) for tokenization.